# PDF.js CORS issue

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm having an issue with PDF.js and CORS configuration.

From domain A I'm loading PDF.js into an iframe with a file as parameter (full path to the server, which will return a pdf document). PDF.js will create a request to the server at domain B with `origin: domain A`. The server at domain B returns the pdf document with header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain A`, so far so good.

In my network tab I see the request to the server, which is returning a 200 status OK, but PDF.js is throwing an error `Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF <url>`.

The question is, what's going on here, CORS seems to be ok, but I can't really get any more info from PDF.js what the real reason is the PDF is failing to load. Is there anyone who encountered the same?

Comment: Try without an iFrame. There are security restraints on iFrames

Comment: @mplungjan From the docs it should work if CORS is setup the right way, which seems to me ok in my case, so I would like to know why this doesn't work. Also I don't want to create conflicts with css/js of existing page, so canvas would be the only alternative I guess, not sure if this would run smoothly in browsers like IE9 which I have to support

Comment: take a look https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1000#issuecomment-133756244, does it help?

Comment: That's an alternative indeed, but I'd like to know why above case is not working...

Comment: Looks like your CORS setup does not work (BTW, having 200 OK for rejected by CORS HTTP requests is normal). If you convinced that your setup is right, try using regular XHR request without/instead of PDF.js app. If this will work, look at web worker location origin. Also legacy browsers have issue with CORS -- provide more info and link to your app in the question.

Comment: This might help, https://jsfiddle.net/6wxnd9uu/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the problem. My server was not passing the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header to the response, which was needed (xhr request was sent with `xhr.withCredential`).

CORS is now working properly.

Found the solution at: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 14):

PDF.js community is not helpful, and years later still no definitive answer to get the viewer.html working, with cors. To bypass all the JS code preventing you from cross browser issues, you can do these steps:

This solution is to use their default viewer.html, which is already nicely done, with css and all features), and NOT HAVE TO build your entire viewer itself.

1. Ensure when you use pdf.js, your request sends header - ORIGIN
2. Ensure whatever server you are using, you can append headers for CORS,

IE: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

As you know, to use the viewer, you should use: https://yourserver/dir/viewer.html?file=PDF_URL

the URL of pdf should be urlencoded so when you pass the link, use the code:

```html
var urlEncoded = encodeURI(url);
```

### Edit viewer.js

1. Search for the function which loads your PDF file/URL (line ~1325):
   "var loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsLib.getDocument)" or "getDocument"
2. Above that line, get the url for the pdf from the get params, when you called viewer.html?file=url  (which may have get params, if you use CDN servers):

```html
/*
fetch the filename and params from the [viewer.html?file=some.place/on.the/internet/somefile.pdf?Expiry=2343243&somekey=3342343&other], which is the part [some.place/on.the/internet/somefile.pdf?Expiry=2343243&somekey=3342343&other]
Note: Use regex if you please.... Here is just for simplicity sake
*/
let _realURL =  window.location.href;

// split away the html and get the file=xxxx
let getParamsIndex = _realURL.indexOf("?");
let fileParamKeyValue = _realURL.substring(getParamsIndex+1);

// get the pdf file plus all it's required get params (if exists)
let getEqualsIndex = fileParamKeyValue.indexOf("=");
let pdfFile = fileParamKeyValue.substring(getEqualsIndex+1);


//original line to search
loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsLib.getDocument)(parameters);
```

3. Now you have the pdf file, you change the existing code as below:

```html
//don't use this which breaks if your pdf requires get parameters
//var loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsLib.getDocument)(parameters);
//uses the pdfFile url link we created above
var loadingTask = (0, _pdfjsLib.getDocument)(pdfFile);
```

4. Search for "throw new Error('file origin does not match", about line 1865
5. Comment out this javascript check for file origin

```html
 if (fileOrigin !== viewerOrigin) {
        //don't throw the error, allow the file to be retrieved!!!!
        //throw new Error('file origin does not match viewer\'s');
 }
```

6. Note: on line 1853, you will see -

```html
var HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS = ['null', 'http://mozilla.github.io', 'https://mozilla.github.io'];
```

You could use this to specify specific servers to allow for CORS, but by disabling the throws exception, you can accept any server. Anyways, why would they even put this HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS in the base code, if they wanted us to use it?

Comment: "This solution is to use their default viewer.html," Also FWIW, I think you're better off redoing the viewer from scratch. It's severely limited. For example you can't zoom in more than 1000% even though pdf.js can render to arbitrary resolution using the viewport parameter. It also has no touch support and doesn't even respond to simple things like ctrl+wheel. PDF.JS itself is a good _renderer_ but that's all I'd use it for.

Comment: Hello Peter. I agree. This was written a long time ago and after hours of figuring out how to change the base code to get it to work for external links. 

Now there probably are better choices, I haven't had to update the software for our current systems as most people can easily download PDF viewer now or have it already downloaded. This was a solution to show a PDF in a mobile app which I wrote a while ago. I will come back to this at some point in the future, as I will come back to update our entire mobile app, and I will post relevant links to something better, if found.

Comment: Hi @sboy you're absolutely right and I really should have pointed out your answer is very helpful, so thank you! I just came out of 3 weeks of working a custom PDF viewer using PDF.JS - works great in Chrome but am now trying to get it working on iOS... Would love to hear if you find anything else useful. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the step by step guide but I keep getting "Access to fetch at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Answer (score 1):

CORS issue also comes to me with PDF.js when I was providing the path to my PDF file in pdfjslib.getDocument. I resolved this issue by providing data URI of pdf file in getDocument method. I make data URI of pdf file as:

```
dataURI = "data:text/plain;base64," + (Get base64 of PDF from online tool or you can generate it by javascript as well);
```

Comment: how do you generate it via js?

Comment: Amazing, it worked on Chrome and FF. Not IE tough...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue when implemented pdfjs in React. pdfjs provides us `withCredentials` option which is use for CORS, you should turn it as true then it solved the problem. Here is my example:

```js
const loadingTask = pdfjs.getDocument({
    url: pdfUrl,
    withCredentials: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and solved it as follows:
if you have download pdfjs and use it in public folder

[image]

use it like this

[image]

with the local file there is no error, but if using a url it will get a CORS error

To fix this when running locally or in production, simply navigate to the `HOSTED_VIEWER_ORIGINS` variable and add the domain `http://localhost` in the file `viewer.js`

you guys can edit the toolbar in the `viewer.html` file,

pdfjs version use is `3.9.179`
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download

[image]